# Passing ILogger into DI in .net core console results in service not registered error

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, serilog

I have a service that I use both in ASP.NET Core 2.2 and would like to to use in .NET Core 2.2 Console app. FYI, I am using Serilog from configuration if that makes any difference

Class to reference/use

```
public RabbitMq(ILogger<RabbitMq> logger, ...)
    {
       ...
        this.logger = logger;

    }
```

ASP.NET CORE `Startup.cs` **EVERYTHING WORKS IN ASP.NET CORE**

```
 var busConfig = Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMQ").Get<RabbitMqConf>();
        services.AddSingleton<IEventBus, RabbitMq>(x =>
        {
            var logger = x.GetRequiredService<ILogger<RabbitMq>>();
            return new RabbitMq(logger, busConfig.Host, busConfig.Username, busConfig.Password, busConfig.Queue, busConfig.RetryCount);
        });
```

As you can see I am able to use `.GetRequiredService<ILogger<RabbitMq>>` and it properly brings back a logger to pass into the `ctor` of the `RabbitMq`

.NET Core 2.2 **Console** app error is

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[RabbitMQ.RabbitMq]' has been
>   registered.'

On this line `var logger = x.GetRequiredService<ILogger<RabbitMq>>();`

```
class Program
{
    private static string _env;
    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

    static Program()
    {


        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        Log.Information($"Environment: {_env}");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var busConfig = Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMQ").Get<RabbitMqConf>();

        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()

            .AddSingleton<IEventBus, RabbitMq>(x =>
            {
                var logger = x.GetRequiredService<ILogger<RabbitMq>>();

                return new RabbitMq(logger, busConfig.Host, busConfig.Username, busConfig.Password, busConfig.Queue, busConfig.RetryCount);
            })

            .BuildServiceProvider();

        var eventBus = serviceProvider.GetService<IEventBus>();
        eventBus.Subscribe<CoinAddedEvent, CoinAddedEventHandler>();


    }
    public class CoinAddedEvent : IntegrationEvent
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class CoinAddedEventHandler
        : IIntegrationEventHandler<CoinAddedEvent>
    {
        public Task Handle(CoinAddedEvent @event)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@event.Name);
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using serilog - you need to register that too.

Comment: Yes I am using Serilog (just added a fyi to the OP)

Comment: You aren't registering the logger by calling `AddLogging`.  Asp.Net Core does this for you.  In a console app you need to do it.  https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/02/14/net-core-console-logging/

Comment: registering/add serilog itself as well did the trick